# Stock Price Prediction: Underperforming LSTM Model Compared to Regular Regression - Seeking Guidance

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, hyperparameters

My dissertation is about Predicting Stock prices. In my case I am using an LSTM model and a various technical indicators. the problem is that now a normal regression model is outperforming my LSTM model. So I thought it might be that my Hyperparameters are not optimal.
The dataset I'm using has the following features and goes back to 2008 recording daily Close prices until today:
' Open  High    Low Close   Volume  BOLL_Middle BOLL_Upper  BOLL_Lower  MACD    CCI ATR EMA_20  MA5 MA10    MTM6    MTM12   ROC SMI WVAD    USDX '

Below is my LSTM model:

```
# Reshape the input data to be [samples, timesteps, features]
train_features_reshaped = np.reshape(train_features.values, (train_features.shape[0], 1, train_features.shape[1]))
val_features_reshaped = np.reshape(val_features.values, (val_features.shape[0], 1, val_features.shape[1]))
test_features_reshaped = np.reshape(test_features.values, (test_features.shape[0], 1, test_features.shape[1]))

# Determine the number of features in the input data
num_columns = train_features.shape[1]

# Define your custom learning rate
learning_rate = 0.01

# Initialize the model
model = Sequential()

# First LSTM layer with Dropout regularization
model.add(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(1, num_columns)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Second LSTM layer with Dropout regularization
model.add(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Third LSTM layer with Dropout regularization
model.add(LSTM(units=100))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Fully Connected layer (Dense Layer)
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu'))

# Output layer
model.add(Dense(units=1))

# Compile the model with the custom learning rate
optimizer = Adam(lr=learning_rate)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse')

# Define the ModelCheckpoint callback to save the best model based on validation loss
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True, mode='min', verbose=1)

# Train the model and save the training history
history = model.fit(train_features_reshaped, train_target, epochs=35, batch_size=64, 
                    validation_data=(val_features_reshaped, val_target),
                    callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])

# Load the best model based on validation loss
best_model = load_model('best_model.h5')

# Evaluate the best model on the test set
loss = best_model.evaluate(test_features_reshaped, test_target)

# Make predictions using the best model
predictions = best_model.predict(test_features_reshaped)
```

Comment: If  this is your dissertation then you should have evidence of how you have changed each and every parameter and the subsequent results. Which parameter were you changing that caused a decrease in performance?

Comment: Hyperparameters may not be optimal so you should try tuning for them. A second reason might be that you are using a deep network with multiple layers of LSTM. You may reduce them or increase the data size.